# Can you suggest a good book for Prototypal Inheritance?

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance, prototypal

I've gone through Javascript: The Good Parts and currently reading Javascript Patterns, but would like to do some in-depth reading on Protoypal Inheritance. It doesn't have to be a JS book but if it then it would be a bonus. I want to read more about how it came into existance and what are its important tenets rather than just reading a single chapter on what it is. Any suggestions?

Comment: This website, plus the rest of the internet hosts a lot of answers, tutorials and code demos about prototypal inheritance. It's just a matter of searching. To narrow down your search, [here's a catalog of free books listed down here in StackOverflow.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/194812/575527)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's only 1 real answer to this question, and the Guru's should/would/will back me up on this:

O'Reilly - JavaScript: The Definitive Guide

Crockford claims that there are many, many terrible books on JS out there, and that this is the least bad of them all. Which, I guess in his universe, is a form of praise. Anyway, if it's OK by his standards, it should be on your short-list.

Comment: Thanks, El. I'm wondering if there are books dedicated to Prototypal Inheritance as we have books on OOPS etc...I mean more detailed...

Comment: Well, I haven't read it, but I gather [Pro JavaScript Techniques](http://jspro.org/) has a substantial section dedicated to prototypal inheritance, but perhaps [this wiki-book](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/JavaScript/Constructors_and_Prototypes) is a good place to start, too. Just watch DC's youtube clips and read his articles after that. I personally like his take on prototypal inheritance (especially what he refers to as _powerconstructors_)

Comment: Just looked at the wiki, it's not a good place to start (it's close to empty) - Also: No, I don't know of any books that deal with prototypal inheritance as such. Perhaps it's a good time for someone to get cracking, there might just be a market for it :-P

Comment: :) Yup, It's amazing how little is available on it out there...I'm wondering whether I've to go back to Self and Scheme to know more about it.

Comment: Scheme will teach you more about the power of the functional paradigm then prototypes. I think that the closest to a fully span out explanation you'll get is _shiver_ ActionScript _shiver_ books, it's a variation of ECMA anyhow, and v3 isn't thát bad. They've just attempted to turn it in a regular OO language a bit too much, so now it's neither here nor there

Comment: @SidharthPanwar: Just thought of another book that is definitely worth a closer look: _JavaScript: The Good Parts, By Douglas Crockford_ I think it was published by O'Reilly, too

Comment: Yup. Gone through that...see the question description...